# How to return from Dispatch queue loop which gives me a error alert 4 times continuously?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, phonegap-plugins

I am downloading a PDF file from server using dispatch queue and loading on present-view as PDF preview which is working fine when a valid PDF url is available.

But when a  broken URL link comes from server, I have called a alert view to show an error message to User.
Whereas this alert POP's up multiple times..

Can someone help me to return from this loop.

```
     - (void)viewPdf:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
    {
        if (command.arguments[0] == (id)[NSNull null])
        {
            [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR] callbackId:command.callbackId];
            return;
        }

        NSString *requestIdStr;
        NSDictionary* options = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

        if ([command.arguments count] > 0) {
            options = [command argumentAtIndex:0];
            requestIdStr = [options objectForKey:@"requestId"];
        }
        NSString *url = requestIdStr;

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,(unsigned long)NULL), ^(void)
               {
                   NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
                   NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PDF.pdf"]];
                   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                   [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
                   [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Error... %@",error);//Console message shown below
                        NSLog(@"pdf downloaded, opening...");
                        NSData *pdf = data;
                        CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)pdf);
                        CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);

                        if (document == nil) {
                            // error
                            NSLog(@"%@",@"error PDF broken link");


                         //***********  This alert Pops up multiple times ************//
                            UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Error while opening PDF" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                            [alert show];
                           // return ;// I have used this "return " but no use
                           //Or am I calling this alertview view at wrong place
                          //*************************************** //

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            NSURL *localURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:file];
                            [pdf writeToFile:file options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
                            self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:localURL];
                            [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];
                            [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:NO];
                         }
                         CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
                        CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);
                    }];
               });
 [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK] callbackId:command.callbackId];
     }
```

**Console Message When a invalid url is downloaded:**

> Error...... Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1007 "too many HTTP redirects" UserInfo=0x7aed5a80 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://vpcsapp.com/upload/media/details/image/2/1?1439449808478, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://vpcsapp.com/upload/media/details/image/2/1?1439449808478, NSLocalizedDescription=too many HTTP redirects, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ae8ab80 "too many HTTP redirects"}
>   failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you all

Comment: Try showing the alert on main thread and checking the error variable.